# How to add a property to a dynamically changing object from an API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

I hope someone can help me with my problem! I didn't find the right thing through the search and maybe someone can give me a hint.

I am calling an API that returns an object that in turn contains nested objects. In these nested objects there are two properties "value" and "scale". I want to divide these two properties and write them as properties in the same object.

The data I get from the API is dynamic, which means it is constantly changing.

Example:

```
// call api

const apiCall = callApi(...);

// return object
console.log(apiCall);

{
    id: '3454353458764389759834534534',
    json_data: {
        persons: {
            de: {
                name: 'Bob',
                data: {
                    scale: 100,
                    value: 2459,
                },
            },
            be: {
                name: 'Alice',
                data: {
                    scale: 10000,
                    value: 1459,
                },
            },
        },
        url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/',
        timestamp: '2021-10-23T12:00:11+00:00',
        disclaimer: 'Some bla bla',
    },
}
```

```
// targed object


const objTarged = {
    id: '3454353458764389759834534534',
    json_data: {
        persons: {
            de: {
                name: 'Bob',
                data: {
                    scale: 100,
                    value: 2459,
                    result: 24.59 // value / scale = result
                },
            },
            be: {
                name: 'Alice',
                data: {
                    scale: 10000,
                    value: 1459,
                    result: 0.1459 // value / scale = result
                },
            },
        },
        url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/',
        timestamp: '2021-10-23T12:00:11+00:00',
        disclaimer: 'Some bla bla',
    },
};
```

My thoughts:

- do I need to map the object into a new object?
- how can I do this if the source object is constantly changing (Object.values?)
- How can I write the result of Value / Scale as a new property in the same object each time I call the API?

Big thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be helpful to decompose the problem into first finding the nested objects with the keys you're interested in.  Having done that, it will be easy to augment those objects with the desired calculation.

Below is a sort of generic function that finds a nested object based on it having a particular key. With that, `fixMyApiData` writes itself...

```js
// return an array of objects that are nested in the passed object which contain the passed key
function objectsContainingKey(object, key) {
  let results = [];
  Object.keys(object).forEach(k => {
    if (k === key) results.push(object);
    if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object')
      results = results.concat(objectsContainingKey(object[k], key));
  });
  return results;
}

// find the nested objects we care about and augment them with the value/scale calculation
function fixMyApiData(apiData) {
  objectsContainingKey(apiData, 'scale').forEach(data => {
    if (data.value) data.result = data.value / data.scale;
  })
}

let apiData = {
  id: '3454353458764389759834534534',
  json_data: {
    persons: {
      de: {
        name: 'Bob',
        data: {
          scale: 100,
          value: 2459,
        },
      },
      be: {
        name: 'Alice',
        data: {
          scale: 10000,
          value: 1459,
        },
      },
    },
    url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/',
    timestamp: '2021-10-23T12:00:11+00:00',
    disclaimer: 'Some bla bla',
  },
};

fixMyApiData(apiData);
console.log(apiData);
```

Comment: Thank you also your solution also works great I can unfortunately only accept one solution. But I will look at both very closely and deal more intensively with objects.

Comment: All good. The purpose of accepting an answer is to indicate the one you most used to solve the problem. Incidentally, please note that the other answer adds the scale calculation to any object with “data” as its key. It will err if “scale” or “value” is missing. This one does the division only if those two keys are present. Whether that matters depends on the range of api results.

Comment: Yes you are right! I have also decided for your solution because I think that it is also better downward compatible. At least as far as I have read. I had also checked in advance for "undefined" in my version. So slowly a picture emerges. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `mapValues()` function that takes an object, and creates a new object by passing each of the object's values in a transforming function.

Whenever the api call returns a new object, we recreate the new object with the `result` property according to the structure.

**How does the `mapValues` function works?**

Whenever an object (or array) is passed to `mapValues`, it's converted to an array of `[key, value]` pairs. The pairs are then mapped to new `[key, pair]` entries by applying `transformFn` to the value. The transform array of pairs is then converted back to an using `Object.fromEntries()`.

```js
const mapValues = (transformFn, obj) => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
  .map(([key, value]) => [key, transformFn(value)])
)

const apiCall = {"persons":{"de":{"name":"Bob","scale":100,"value":2459},"be":{"name":"Alice","scale":10000,"value":1459}}}

const result = mapValues(
  val => mapValues(v => ({
    ...v,
    result: v.value / v.scale,
  }), val),
  apiCall
)

console.log(result)
```

If you have multiple nested levels with properties you don't want to transform, we can also pass the `key` to the `transformFn` for a more granular change. Now we can create a recursive function to traverse the tree, and only update objects which have a specific key.

```js
const mapValues = (transformFn, obj) => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
  .map(([key, value]) => [key, transformFn(value, key)])
)

const fn = obj => mapValues(
  (val, key) => {
    // if the key is data create a new object with a result property
    if(key === 'data') return ({
      ...val,
      result: val.value / val.scale,
    })
    
    // if it's object pass it to the recursive function
    if(typeof val === 'object') return fn(val)

    return val
  },
  obj
)

const apiCall = {"id":"3454353458764389759834534534","json_data":{"persons":{"de":{"name":"Bob","data":{"scale":100,"value":2459}},"be":{"name":"Alice","data":{"scale":10000,"value":1459}}},"url":"https://stackoverflow.com/","timestamp":"2021-10-23T12:00:11+00:00","disclaimer":"Some bla bla"}}

const result = fn(apiCall)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Damn, I've been sitting here for an hour picking apart your solution, but I don't understand how to nest my function to do the calculation in the correct object? I really want to understand it, I'm already reading the documentation for "Object.entries" and "map".

I have edited my example object again.